# MySQL Trigger. Should I use INSERT or UPDATE

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a table named members in which there is a field named ref (varchar 50), amongst others. There are certian inserts that occur in this table with a specific ref, "TESTREF"

Basically what I need is that a record is inserted with this ref then the ref should be changed to another "NEWREF"

I belive I need to create a before trigger on the table (there is already an after trigger which moves data to another table) but I'm not sure if I should use UPDATE or INSERT command on the ref.

The correct syntax is

```
 BEGIN
IF (NEW.ref = 'TESTREF') THEN
SET NEW.ref = 'NEWREF';
END IF;
END
```

Comment: Yes, it can be done. Use BEFORE INSERT/BEFORE UPDATE triggers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this value changes only when new record is inserted then use BEFORE INSERT.
I assume that when later the record is updated then the ref field is not set back to TESTREF.

Comment: Hi, the ref will never be updated only inserted. Does my command above look ok?

Comment: In general yes, but I'm not too familiar with trigger syntax - it might be slightly different in different database.

Comment: OK thanks, I found the correct syntax and will edit my code above